# MySQL left join query too slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this SQL query to join two tables and it takes 10 seconds even with a limit of 10. I've checked if the tables are indexed and they are so I'm out of ideas. Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM client_registration_request
LEFT JOIN customers ON (client_registration_request.customer_reference=customers.reference) 
LEFT JOIN region_info ON ( customers.country = region_info.id ) 
WHERE client_registration_request.client = 23
LIMIT 10
```

Here are the results from explain select

[image: explain select]

client_registration_request index

[image: client_registration_request index]

customers index

[image: customers index]

and region_info index
[image: and region_info index]

Comment: Run `explain select ...` and add the output here aling with the indexes you created

Comment: Try using `explain` the query and post the result into the question.

Comment: please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: For some reason although you have an index on reference it is being ignored. I would suggest forcing the use of that index just to check for an improvement. Might be worth repairing the table to update the index.

Comment: what is the datatype and size of `client_registration_request.customer_reference` and `customers.reference`. Often index fails on joining condition when the joining keys are different data type

Comment: The type is varchar for both of them. The only difference is that customer's varchar is 16 in size and `client_registration_request.customer_reference` is of 255

Comment: If they are not necessary to be as `varchar` change them to `int` in both tables and if its needs to be `varchar` make them same in both tables and rubuit the indexes after dropping previous index on these 2 columns.

Comment: Note that in the absence of an ORDER BY clause, a LIMIT clause is (fairly) meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

always make sure the fields you are using for your `JOIN` - conditions are indexed:

```
ALTER TABLE `client_registration_request` ADD INDEX `customer_reference` (`customer_reference`);
ALTER TABLE `customers` ADD INDEX `reference` (`reference`);
```

.. and so on.

**update:** your `EXPLAIN` shows that your indexed keys `customers` table are not used. so try to re-index them:

```
ALTER TABLE `customers` ADD INDEX `reference` (`reference`);
ALTER TABLE `customers` ADD INDEX `country` (`country`);
```

Comment: I'm getting `#1061 - Duplicate key name 'reference'` by trying to `ALTER TABLE `customers` ADD INDEX `reference` (`reference`);`

Comment: @phcm then just take another name: `ALTER TABLE customers ADD INDEX reference (reference2);` for example

Comment: Still slow. @Juancho Ramone's answer makes the query faster. It takes 5 seconds; better but still slow.

Comment: @phcm So promote that answer then!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written the query is limiting and filtering the results after the two left join have performed, that's why it's taking the same time to query.

To make it quicker you need to limit and filter it as soon as possible, in your case you want to limit and filter it before any join.

As you are using LEFT JOINS, you can limit and filter the first table and still get the same result. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM client_registration_request WHERE client_registration_request.client = 23 LIMIT 10) client_registration_request_TMP
LEFT JOIN customers ON (client_registration_request_TMP.customer_reference=customers.reference) 
LEFT JOIN region_info ON ( customers.country = region_info.id )
```

Comment: it's just that he got no indexes on his `customers` table, imho.

Comment: Customers table does have an index on the reference field (that is the field used in the join), just the query isn't using that index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query, using table aliases (so I find it easier to follow):

```
SELECT *
FROM client_registration_request crr LEFT JOIN
     customers c
     ON crr.customer_reference = c.reference LEFT JOIN
     region_info r
     ON c.country = r.id
WHERE crr.client = 23
LIMIT 10
```

The most important index is on on `client_registration_request(client)`.  But, I would include the other `join` columns in this.  So, the first index is `client_registration_request(client, reference, country)`.  You can create this as:

```
create index idx_client_registration_request_3 on client_registration_request(client, reference, country);
```

I assume that the keys in the other tables are already primary keys or indexed.  If not, you should build indexes on them too `customer(reference)` and `region_info(country)`.

Using a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is suspicious.  You will be getting an arbitrary set of matching rows when you run the query -- you cannot guarantee that two runs would return the same set.